# Skewness and kurtosis of given array

Tags: probability, statistics

I have given array: [1, 3, 5, 6]. How to calculate skewness and kurtosis of it? There is lots of formulas and I don't know which of them to apply? Also there is different calculators which calculate it differently

[example 1](http://www.endmemo.com/statistics/kurtosis.php): 1.180049,

[example 2](https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/kurtosis.php): 1.57339844872

Please explain how to calculate it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two values are the respective third and fourth central statistical moments.
AFAIK they're commonly defined to be

$$
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    skewness &= N^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^N \left(\frac{x_k - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 \\
    kurtosis &= N^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^N \left(\frac{x_k - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^4 \\
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
$$

for data $x = \{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}$.

Also cf the definitions for [skewness](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Skewness.html) and [kurtosis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kurtosis.html).

So for the calculation of the values, you start by calculating the mean value over the array $a$ of length $N$:

$$ \mu = N^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^N a_k $$

After that, one needs to compute the standard deviation $\sigma$:

$$ \sigma^2 = N^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^N \left(a_k - \mu\right)^2 $$

Note that some definitions require $\sigma$ to be divided by $N-1$ instead of $N$.

Having both $\mu$ and $\sigma$, you can compute the skewness and kurtosis of the array.

Now we apply this to the array $a = [1,3,5,6]$:

$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
  \mu &= \frac{1}{4} \left(1+3+5+6\right) = 3.75 \\
  \sigma &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} \left((1-3.75)^2+(3-3.75)^2+(5-3.75)^2+(6-3.75)^2\right)} = 1.92 \\
  skewness &= \frac{1}{4}\left((\frac{1-3.75}{1.92})^3+(\frac{3-3.75}{1.92})^3+(\frac{5-3.75}{1.92})^3+(\frac{6-3.75}{1.92})^3\right) = -0.278 \\
  kurtosis &= \frac{1}{4}\left((\frac{1-3.75}{1.92})^4+(\frac{3-3.75}{1.92})^4+(\frac{5-3.75}{1.92})^4+(\frac{6-3.75}{1.92})^4\right) = 1.574 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
$$

Simple verification using Python's `numpy`:

```
>>> np.mean([1,3,5,6])
3.75
>>> np.std([1,3,5,6])
1.920286436967152
>>> 0.25 * sum(map(lambda x: ((float(x)-3.75)/1.92)**3, [1,3,5,6]))
-0.278155008951823
>>> 0.25 * sum(map(lambda x: ((float(x)-3.75)/1.92)**4, [1,3,5,6]))
1.5743375744348693
```

Comment: This answer gives no explanation. I do not understand that formulas. Can you please show how to calculate with numbers of given array?

Comment: Why online calculators calculate it differently?

Comment: @TeodorKolev Sorry, forgot the square root. Check again. The differnce might arise from different scaling in the standard deviation.

Comment: Yet again, numbers are different than calculators

Comment: Why? The second calculate says 1.573... and my result is 1.574, but notice for simplicity I rounded to two digits, as the Python version shows. Thus with the usual definitions, the second calculator is right.

Comment: Skewness should be something like -0.2408

Comment: That's strange ... I don't know, how did you get this value? What definition are you using, or what scaling factors?

Comment: and std should be 2.2173557826083

Comment: Again: Be careful with scaling factors. The definitions I used seems to be the most widely used ones, and common implementations also use them (cf the numpy output).